# Processing Run on Android

Tags: android, compiler-construction, sdk, processing

So I'm trying to test out processing for Android. I have a simple sketch ready and want to run it on my Android device. But I cant get it to work. And it isn't a problem with my sketch; the example sketches also won't run. I have the SDK downloaded and configured correctly but when I compile it and run, it gives me this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/Gurpreet/Desktop/Programming/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/Gurpreet/Desktop/Programming/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

What can I do to get my sketch to run on my phone?

Comment: Can you please give some more information? What OS are you on? What steps have you taken to setup your development device? Is the code able to run on the emulator?

Comment: I'm on a mac, I have a gs4 running 4.2, and I have the latest version of processing. I downloaded the sdk (not adt bundle) and got api 10 downloaded, build tools, etc. Then I pull up an example sketch and hit build and neither emulator or phone work.

Comment: And developer mode and such are on. When I run my existing stuff off eclipse it works. Also the path to the sdk in processing is correct

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of error and it was because of this 2 things, first I needed to install the driver for my cell phone and then set my phone to develop mode.
Try doing this 2 things.

Regards Jose.